# Why do programmers still use "SAFE_DELETE"?

Tags: c++, memory

If I had a dime for every time I've seen this macro in use, today I would be coding just for fun:

```
#define SAFE_DELETE(p) if ((p) != NULL) { delete (p); (p) = NULL; }
```

Why do programmers insist in keep using this macro when `delete` checks for null? Is is because it sets the pointer to null at the end? Then why not at least rewrite it and remove the redundant check:

```
#define SAFE_DELETE(p) { delete (p); (p) = NULL; }
```

Still, it doesn't seem like a good practice.

Comment: For some reason there is a considerable amount of superstition surrounding `NULL` checks with `delete` and `free()`. I suspect the fact that these checks are harmless make them justifiable in the minds of those who haven't read the documentation.

Comment: "avoid asking subjective questions where … your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”" ([help/dont-ask])

Comment: One possible justfication is if it's a micro-optimisation.  If delete results in a function call, then SAFE_DELETE avoids that call if the pointer is null.

Comment: One word: Cargo cult programming.

Comment: Simon, I never though about the micro-otimization thing. It's a valid point for some very specific cases. @ThomasEding, thanks for introducing me to a new term! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is (a) a rant and (b) asking for psychological insight rather than solving a genuine problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me put it this way.  Does it *seem* like something C++ would do?  C++ is replete with gotchas and undefined behavior, but in this one instance, it helpfully validates a parameter for you?  Every other "safer" language you know throws an exception if you try to do *anything* with a null pointer, but the unsafest language you use just handles it cleanly? It's not self-consistent.  People take the safe approach because in nearly every other case, C++ *forces* the programmer to take the safe approach.  In other words, in C++ code, "Bring Your Own Validation" is idiomatic and habitual.  It doesn't look right when it's missing.

Comment: +1 I have been guilty of this, for exactly those reasons.

Comment: I'm not sure if a agree with the case that `delete` accepting null quietly is inconsistent. Termination/shutdown in C++ is supposed to be fail-safe, inasmuch as possible. Destructors can't throw exceptions, so it kind of makes sense that `delete` is tolerating of a null pointer.

Comment: @glampert: There in nothing in C++ that stops you from throwing an exception in a destructor. It is just considered bad form, because it can cause abrupt termination of the program.

Comment: Exactly, @Bart.  A great example of C++ programmers habitually providing their own safety.